# How to retrieve incoming SMS from GoIP to PHP?

Tags: php, sms, gsm, sms-gateway

I am trying to build a codeigniter/php app that can send and receive SMS using GoIP GSM Modem. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941059/how-to-send-retrieve-sms-from-goip) answered the sending part.

Now, how do I retrieve SMS in PHP?

My idea right now, is for the modem to send a POST request to my server every time there's a new SMS received but I can't seem to find the right API or sms-server to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on GSM modems, but it seems unlikely to me you'd be able to have the modem initiate HTTP requests to your PHP application when it receives a message.

Based on a little Googling though, it seems that you can poll the modem with AT commands:

```
> AT
OK
> AT+CMGF=1
OK
> AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+85291234567",,"06/11/11,00:30:29+32"
Hello, welcome to our SMS tutorial.
+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+85291234567",,"06/11/11,00:32:20+32"
A simple demo of SMS text messaging.

OK
```

(The above example is from here: https://www.developershome.com/sms/howToReceiveSMSUsingPC.asp)

So you could poll the modem every minute or so, looking for new SMS messages it has received. Communicating with the modem from PHP is going to depend on how the modem is connected, but you might find this example repository useful: https://github.com/gonzalo123/gam-sms/

It's written by Gonzalo Ayuso, and there is some explanation on its usage here: https://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/21/howto-sendread-smss-using-a-gsm-modem-at-commands-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest implementation would be to install the accompanying SMS Server application. Let your GoIP device register to your SMS Server and let the API do the sending and receiving.

What you want to achieve via POST is already built into the Server application. Check the documentation here:

http://www.voipddns.net/pdf/GoIP%20SMS%20AppNote.pdf

Method 1 is the simplest way.

I hope it helps.